# Can we share the same database but different tables between micro services

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, microservices

We have two microservices which have different business logic. Assume business logic is quite complex hence decided to split it into new service but the domain is same. This new service requires some new tables to be introduced along with accessing few old tables.

For the above scenario,
Can we share the same database but with different tables?

Database Name: 'general'.

Table Name: 'general.table1' => accessed by service1(Has CRUD APIs on table1 data).
Table Name: 'general.table2' => accessed by service2(Has CRUD APIs on table2 data).

Both services connect to same database and load on the APIs for both services are similar.
People are saying it's an anti-pattern most of the places on web.
Can you please put all the pros and cons for this approach? It it still okay or really bad design?

Comment: I think you are decomposing your µs the wrong way. You need to apply functional decomposition. A µs is a component of a bigger application (a module if you want) that serves a purpose. It's not a web service (totally different concept) and it's not related to a single table. A single µs can emcompass 20 tables and 50 web services, or can emcompass a single table with 1 web service. The important idea is that it should be a unit of logic that concentrates a single responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

Shared database is an anti-pattern. But at the end of the day it's a trade-off to make - "ideal architecture" vs business value. Technical/architecture debt is a tool; if one never uses it, it's a problem - if one uses only that tool, it's also the problem.

With a single database and different tables I would make sure that every service has its own user, and those users' access is scoped to specific tables. This is a small tactical thing to make sure services don't get coupled by accident.

Long term coupling is the largest risk with your approach. The time will come, when it will be a task and a deadline; and the easiest way to get there is to read other services table. That will be the moment to make a trade off or push back.

The pros for your approach: less infrastructure to support and a team can became an expert in database support.

From cons side: two different services using the same resource may create a noisy neighbour problem and coupling risks mentioned above.

After sleeping on this, I'll add few more thoughts.

Companies are different how they structure the ownership and where the lines are.

Even when a company uses microservices, they still might have a dedicated Infrastructure teams. For example, these teams may manage database systems, like dedicated team to manage MySQL databases or Cassandra. These teams are responsible for capacity planning, operations and overall support.

Some other companies like to have one full vertical/service being owned by a single team. In that case the team manages their own data layer.

It seems, your company is the first one - teams own microservices, but there is an infrastructure team for the data layer. This approach should not stop you from writing great and decoupled services. As I mentioned above, you could isolate services from each other by giving each one a dedicated database user/role and adjusting permissions accordingly.